# T4 Template cannot find Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle, petapoco

I've a project with .NET 3.5 and PetaPoco 4.0.3 (micro ORM library).
I've also a reference to Oracle.DataAccess.

PetaPoco is a micro ORM library which has a T4 template to create POCO classes automatically from a Database. `Database.tt`contains T4 template and creates a `Database.cs`class.

When I trying to create `Database.cs` from T4 template `Database.tt`, I receive always the same error:

```
Failed to load provider `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` - Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

I' ve debug T4 code generation and I've found that the problem is loading the Oracle driver:

```
/* This a part of T4 Template */
DbProviderFactory _factory;
try
{
    _factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ProviderName);
}
```

Where `ProviderName` is `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`.

I tried to reproduce the problem in my `Program.cs`in the **same** project and it works!

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
    DbProviderFactory _factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Oracle.DataAccess.Client");
    DbConnection dbconnection = _factory.CreateConnection();
        }
    }
```

So, I am not able to understand why in the same project, `DbProviderFactory`can found a driver for `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` but T4 not. Which execution contexts is using T4? What can I do to solve the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ok, I've found the problem...just install "Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio" and works fine.